# How to use Google Analytics ga function as a blocking call?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

For example, I want to send a user timing call using `ga` before the form submit

e.g.

```
ga('send', 'timing', 'test', 'load', xxx);
jQuery('#myform').submit();
```

it seems to me that Google never received my method call as the function is not blocking.

How to make the above code work?

Comment: Its described in the docs: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/sending-hits

Answer (score 0):

You solve this using the hitCallback API,  https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/sending-hits#hitcallback

```js
# assumptions:  #myform is a form, and var xxx exists, jquery loaded

ga('send', 'timing', 'test', 'load', xxx, {
    hitCallback: function() {
      jQuery('#myform').submit();
    }
 });
```

This works by waiting for the GA hit to resolve (ie, return a 200 response) at which point the hitCallback  function is invoked.

You'll probably want to add a timer so that incase there is an error your form will send regardless.  This method is outlined here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/sending-hits#handling_timeouts